# requestAnimationFrame not drawing anything on canvas

Tags: javascript

I have this code to draw out a sine wave on the screen but for some reason nothing comes up on the canvas. It's quite possible it's nothing to do with requestAnimFrame at all however I believe this to be the problem.
The `var y` in the draw function should just be a simple sine wave function of Asin(kx - omega*t), where k is the wavenumber which = 2pi/wavelength.

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx = 0,
    t = 0,
    Amp1 = 200,
    Wav1 = 100,
    omega = 0.01;
function draw(x, t) {
    var y = Amp1 * Math.sin(x(2 * Math.PI / Wav1) - omega * t) + 999;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(t + 100, y);
    ctx.lineTo(t + 100, y + 1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 100);
    };
}());
function animate() {
    setInterval(function () {
        window.requestAnimFrame(animate);
        var newX = cx,
            newT = t;
        cx += 0.5;
        t += 0.5;
        draw(newX, newT);
    }, 50);
}
animate();
```

EDIT: Not really sure why `Amp1` and `Wav1` are coming up cyan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're spawning countless calls to `animate` cause you're calling it every animation frame, and every 50 ms, so remove either the interval or the call to `requestAnimFrame`.

Then, the rest of your code runs right. I'm not sure why you put `+ 999` to `y`, but that's why you see nothing, it simply goes out of the screen (`canvas`). Since I'm not a mathematician I may have broke your sinusoid, but I just wanted to show you it actually works.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx = 0,
  t = 0,
  Amp1 = 200,
  Wav1 = 100,
  omega = 0.01;

function draw(x, t) {
  var y = Amp1 * Math.sin(x*(2 * Math.PI / Wav1) - omega * t);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(t + 100, y);
  ctx.lineTo(t + 100, y + 1);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 100);
  };
}());

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimFrame(animate);
    var newX = cx,
      newT = t;
    cx += 0.5;
    t += 0.5;
    draw(newX, newT);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :p The only reason as to why I was adding 999 was to shift it down the canvas so that it didn't go off screen. Perhaps I went a bit overboard with the shifting. oops.

Comment: Note I also added a `*` operator here : `x*(2 * Math.PI / Wav1)`, cause you were trying to use x as a function, but I assumed a typo.

Comment: Ahhh that was probably why it wasn't working. No typo, just a bad assumption that `x() = x*()`. At least I know for future reference.